# Incremental deployments in a Firebase Hosting project

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have an static site with around 120K pages and a size of around 2GB deployed in a Firebase Hosting project, and this will grow.

All should be deployed in the same domain to be able to keep the user authenticated. Also, different modules are deployed in different paths but same domain (business requirements).

I'm thinking about the way to split the project to allow deployment of only small parts of the project, to avoid to deploy 2GB every day, when there are changes only on few MB of pages.

Is there a way to do incremental deployment in a Firebase Hosting project?

Any other idea?

Comment: It already does incremental deployments.  [Read the section near the end of this blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2018/08/one-project-multiple-sites-plus-boost/) called "Your uploads just got a bit faster, and in some cases a lot faster".

Comment: Sounds like an answer Doug. :)

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, that should be the answer. These type of things should be in the official documentation. Now, I will investigate why still is uploading the full site. Maybe Astro is generating random ids for bundles or something like that. Thanks, for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already does incremental deployments. Read the section near the end of [this blog](https://This%20new%20system%20only%20processes%20new,%20modified,%20or%20deleted%20files.%20You%20know,%20the%20delta.%20This%20means%20any%20files%20that%20are%20unchanged%20aren%E2%80%99t%20uploaded%20when%20you%20run%20firebase%20deploy.%20You%20may%20not%20notice%20a%20big%20improvement%20in%20performance%20if%20your%20site%20is%20only%20a%20few%20files.%20However,%20it%20will%20make%20a%20huge%20difference%20for%20sites%20with%20a%20large%20amount%20of%20existing%20unmodified%20assets.) called "Your uploads just got a bit faster, and in some cases a lot faster".

> This new system only processes new, modified, or deleted files. You know, the delta. This means any files that are unchanged aren’t uploaded when you run firebase deploy. You may not notice a big improvement in performance if your site is only a few files. However, it will make a huge difference for sites with a large amount of existing unmodified assets.